# AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'add_row', 'remove_row' & 'update_row'

Tags: python, kivymd

I have practised the KivyMD DataTable and copied the code from the document to understand how it works. I was surprised when I clicked the button, it came out with an error as follow:

```
    1) self.data_tables.add_row((str(last_num_row + 1), "1", "2", "3"))  
     AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'add_row'  
       
    2) self.data_tables.remove_row(self.data_tables.row_data[-1])   
     AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'remove_row'

    3) self.data_tables.update_row(
      AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'update_row'
```

It is not functioning as what it should be in the  KivyMD documents, I wonder where am I getting wrong? Here is my py file:

datatable_operation.py

```
    from kivy.metrics import dp
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
    from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
    from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
    from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
    
    class Example(MDApp):
        data_tables = None
    
        def build(self):
            layout = MDFloatLayout()  # root layout
            # Creating control buttons.
            button_box = MDBoxLayout(
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                adaptive_size=True,
                padding="24dp",
                spacing="24dp",
            )
    
            for button_text in ["Add row", "Remove row"]:
                button_box.add_widget(
                    MDRaisedButton(
                        text=button_text, on_release=self.on_button_press
                    )
                )

           layout = MDFloatLayout()
               layout.add_widget(
                  MDRaisedButton(
                      text="Change 2 row",
                      pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                      on_release=self.update_row,
                      y=24,
                   )
               )
    
            # Create a table.
            self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
                pos_hint={"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5},
                size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
                use_pagination=False,
                column_data=[
                    ("No.", dp(30)),
                    ("Column 1", dp(40)),
                    ("Column 2", dp(40)),
                    ("Column 3", dp(40)),
                ],
                row_data=[
                    ("1", "1", "2", "3"),
                    ("1", "1", "2", "3"),
                    ],
            )
            # Adding a table and buttons to the toot layout.
            layout.add_widget(self.data_tables)
            layout.add_widget(button_box)

            return layout
    
        def add_row(self):
            last_num_row = int(self.data_tables.row_data[-1][0])
            self.data_tables.add_row((str(last_num_row + 1), "1", "2", "3"))
    
        def remove_row(self):
            if len(self.data_tables.row_data) > 1:
                self.data_tables.remove_row(self.data_tables.row_data[-1])

        def update_row(self, instance_button: MDRaisedButton) -> None:
           self.data_tables.update_row(
               self.data_tables.row_data[1],  # old row data
               ["2", "A", "B", "C"],          # new row data
        )
                
        def on_button_press(self, instance_button: MDRaisedButton) -> None:
            '''Called when a control button is clicked.'''
    
            try:
                {   "Add row": self.add_row,
                    "Remove row": self.remove_row,
                }[instance_button.text]()
            except KeyError:
                pass
               
    Example().run() 

How it could be resolved?
```

Comment: Try formatting your code with proper indentations.

Comment: Have the same issue. Using pip list, my versions are: Kivy 2.1.0, KivyMd 0.104.2. The solution from Robert Pabeschitz is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, using `pip list` found that I was running 0.104.2 which is the latest stable. However, docs on KivyMD mention 1.0.0 and these newer methods appear to be part of the latest work. Updating allowed `update_row` method to compile and function.

Instructions copied below from https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/

> If you want to install development version from master branch, you
> should specify link to zip archive:
>
> pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

Installing the latest and re-running worked great!

`py -m pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip`

`...Successfully installed kivymd-1.0.0.dev0`

Comment: How about update data an error  :  self.data_tables.update_row(
 AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'update_row'

Comment: That is due to using the older KivyMd version, update_row is only supported in 1.0. If you update using the instructions above, the attribute is present.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not an expert by now - had the same problem, my solution is:
Instead of:
self.data_tables.add_row((str(last_num_row + 1), "1", "2", "3"))
I've used:
self.data_tables.row_data.append((str(last_num_row + 1), "1", "2", "3"))
that seems to work pretty well..

should work similarly for remove...

Comment: How about update data an error : self.data_tables.update_row( AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'update_row'